# Assistance with State Machine Event subscription error?

Tags: unity, events, state

My aim is to create events within my various states that will broadcast to other GameObjects when to take certain actions and to send certain data without needing to reference each GameObject.

I have an Event within a concrete State deriving from a base MonoBehaviour State "GallowsBase" in my State machine called "GallowsResetEvent"/"OnGallowsResetEvent":

```
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class GallowsSetup : GallowsBase
{
    public delegate void GallowsResetEvent();
    public static event GallowsResetEvent OnGallowsResetEvent;

    SOWords _wordBank;

    public override void EnterState(GallowsStateManager _gallows)
    {
        // broadcast to observers - reset.
        OnGallowsResetEvent();
        // broadcast to observers - setup.
        // receive setup complete event
        // go to player turn state
        _gallows.SwitchState(_gallows._gallowsTurnPlayer);
        
    }
}
```

When I try to add a listener to the event, I receive an error CS0029 - Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to  'GallowsSetup.OnGallowsResetEvent'

```
private void OnEnable()
{
    GallowsSetup.OnGallowsResetEvent += Reset(); //error here
}


private void Reset()
{
    _textChosenTitle.text = null;
}
```

Changing the void on the Reset method to GallowsSetup.OnGallowsResetEvent gives a couple of errors -

CS0426 The type name 'OnGallowsResetEvent' does not exist in the type 'GallowsSetup'

CS0161 'GallowsCanvas.Reset()': not all code paths return a value

I feel I hit a wall here. How can I implement decoupled events within my state machines?

Comment: Consider using `System.Action` which is an existing zero parameter void delegate type already provided, so you don't need to define your own. But this is all general C# programming syntax you can find covered in more depth on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `GallowsSetup.OnGallowsResetEvent += Reset;`. Without the parenthesis after the method name.

`Reset()` executes the method immediately and uses the returned result in its place. The method returns nothing (aka `void`), so you get an error that void can't be converted to the expected type of the event.

`Reset` refers to the method itself as a delegate value. This allows you to store the method itself in an event so it can be executed by the event later.